# mysql link variable multiple data with one id

Tags: php, mysql

For my thesis at school i'm making a PHP website witch is based on the fantasy football site. And is runned on a localhost server

I'm using a MySQL database for it but have problems finding out how to lay this database out. I already have a players(id, name, team, position) tabel, a user table(id, name, password, id player 1 in squad, id player 2, id player3, id player4) and a table with the matches(id, date,home team, away team, result). But I want to add who scored in that match. How do i do this becaus sometimes 2 people score but there can also be 5 people that score? How do i do this?

All help is really appreciated.

Comment: Try searching for and reading about "normalization".  It is a tricky concept, and it may help to read about it in multiple places that explain it in different ways. The specific part you are violating in your current plan is using columns when you should be using rows in a "join table".  Your user table should not have columns for player ids - instead you should have a join table with rows of player ids that link back to the user table via a foreign key.  Ditto for scoring: that should not be columns in the matches table, it should be in a separate scoring table with matchid as a foreign key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to represent the many-to-many relationship with a players_who_scored linking table. This would look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE players_who_scored (
  player_id INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (player_id) REFERENCES players(id),
  match_id INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (match_id) REFERENCES matches(id),
  PRIMARY KEY (player_id,match_id)
);
```

### update:

if you want to track all stats about a player in a game, then you might add the columns like this:

```
CREATE TABLE player_stats (
  goals INT,
  assists INT,
  yellow_cards INT,
  player_id INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (player_id) REFERENCES players(id),
  match_id INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (match_id) REFERENCES matches(id),
  PRIMARY KEY (player_id,match_id)
);
```

Comment: Ha oke thank you. Didn't know it worked like that(just new to proggaming). So i just have to make an new table players_who_scored(player_id, match_id) right?

Comment: Plus you can add other fields to that table, relevant to the score, like time of score, assisted by, etc etc

Comment: Yea that could come in really helpfull because i need to to add assists and red cards

Comment: I have been trying it out but i'm stuck on something. For the assists and the yellow cards do i just add an extra colum? Like players_who_scored(player_id, scored, assits, yellow card) and just always give the match_ID in these extra colums or not?

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: oke thank you but still what do give in as data in this colums? just a 1 or NULL?

Comment: if a player scores 2 goals and no assists or yellow cards, then the value will be 2 for goals and null for assists and yellow_cards. if he gets 4 assists, 1 goal, and no yellow cards, then the record will have 1 for goal, 4 for assists, and null yellow_cards. then if a player has no goals, assists, or yellow cards, then there will be no record.